# Proper way to deal with translation of content between SE communities

Tags: support, languages, localization

In rare occasions I enter the [Portuguese Stack Overflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) to try and see if there's some interesting question I would like to answer and my problem is that pretty much any interesting question in that community will be answered in the original Stack Overflow.

An example of this would be [my answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98529/o-que-faz-um-popup-ser-bloqueado/98563#98563) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers).

Now, in this specific case I didn't simply translated the question because I was interested in the subject, so I ended up digging a little deeper and I presented a code that proves what I've learned from reading the English answer. But next time I may have nothing else to add and I could end up just translating a question on SO to the PT-SO.

What are the proper ways to handle this? Should my answer include the link of the original answer in English? Or just the name of the User?

Usually this would just be the case of duplicate question, but we're talking about cross-over SE Communities with different primary language.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not a lawyer but from the [CC-ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license I read:

*You are free to share and adapt content as long as you follow the license terms.*

That requires that you must give appropriate credit. You may do so in any reasonable manner.

I consider translating as a form of transforming. So, you can use the English post, translate it into Portuguese and add a link to the author and/or the post and you're good to go. That doesn't violate the CC license nor chapter 3 in the [legal stuff](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: Frankly speaking, this also calls for setting the community wiki flag. YMMV

Comment: @DeerHunter I think providing a full translation is something that should be honored similarly to providing the original answer. It's really hard to translate texts properly

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow - that's why it is important to allow others to correct your translation. Again, our opinions may differ in this regard.